# Extracting connection string from decrypted app config

Tags: xml, vb.net, encryption, app-config

Using RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider, I have encrypted the ConnectionString portion of my app config file where I have a SQL connection string.   This works correctly.

Using this code snippet, I can also retrieve the encrypted connection string portion.

```vb
' Get the application configuration file.
Dim config As System.Configuration.Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)

' Define the Rsa provider name.
Dim provider As String = "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"

' Get the section to protect.
Dim connStrings As ConfigurationSection = config.ConnectionStrings

Dim a As ConfigurationSection = config.ConnectionStrings
Dim xmlData As String = a.SectionInformation.GetRawXml.ToString
Dim doc As XElement = XElement.Parse(xmlData)
Console.WriteLine(doc)
```

doc produces the following string which is correct

```xml
<connectionStrings>
<clear />
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="NorthwindConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=webnetue2;Initial Catalog=Northwind;User ID=aspnet_test;Password=test" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I'm trying to get the various values from this but because its not a properly formatted xml file, nothing seems to work.   I've tried manipulating the string itself but with so many "" in it, it seems improbable that that's the correct way.

Would anyone PLEASE be able to save my sanity?

Comment: You shouldn't need an XElement to parse this stuff. The properties you need should already be in the `config.ConnectionStrings` object (try inspecting it with your Visual Studio debugger).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  You're right in that that the data does appear using the debugger in the variable 'a' above.   It also appears correctly in the xml visualizer.   Unfortunately, I still have the same problem of how to extract the individual values from there,  That's why I wrongly thought getting it into a string might help.